# how to execute postgres query and store it in integer in asp.net core

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, ado.net, npgsql

```
 var mainQuery = String.Format(@"SELECT SUM(amount), accounts.type FROM transactions INNER JOIN accounts ON transactions.accountid = accounts.accountid WHERE accounts.type = 'income' AND transactions.date BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}' GROUP BY accounts.type", startDate, endDate);

 using var mainCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(mainQuery, connection);

 int result = mainCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am executing this query, `mainquery` will return a integer value if executed.

How should I execute this query and store in integer, by using npgsql and ADO.NET?

Comment: First thing to fix is to remove the _string.Format_. This is a form of string concatenation that is very bad practice in creating sql queries. You will get problems with date, decimal and boolean formatting, but most important you create a great opportunity to hack your databases with sql injection. You should always use parameters.

Comment: Second point. ExecuteNonQuery cannot return the data extracted with a Select. You need to use a DataReader or fill a DataAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Since that query should only ever return a single row and you only care about the sum (you already know what the account type is going to be), you should be able to use ExecuteScalar() instead of ExecuteNonQuery().

Steve's first point about String.Format() absolutely still stands, though. The code, as is, has a SQL injection vulnerability and should be refactored.